# Display Multiple Data in Label VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If Column 2 is equal ChosenDate when the button is clicked, the Label Box in VBA will display all the row data of Column 6.  But I can only display one data. and if the value ChosenDate is changed the data diplayed in Label Box will also be changed.

```
 Dim DateChosen As Date
 Dim i As Integer

 DateChosen = "2020/07/20"
        For i = 10 To 5000 
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = DateChosen Then
             EventLabel.Caption = Range("F" & i)
            End If
        Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing of

```
EventLabel.Caption = Range("F" & i)
```

with

```
EventLabel.Caption = EventLabel.Caption & Range("F" & i) & VbCrLf 'to be displayed one on top of the other
```

or

```
EventLabel.Caption = EventLabel.Caption & Range("F" & i) & ", "' to be dsplayed one after the other
```

Edited:

In order to keep only the last iteration/processing result, your code must previously clear the caption:

```
EventLabel.Caption = ""
For i = 10 To 5000
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = DateChosen Then
        EventLabel.Caption = EventLabel.Caption & Range("F" & i) & VbCrLf
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: it works! but if the ChosenDate value is changed for example from DateChosen = "2020/07/20" to DateChosen = "2020/07/23". It will still display the data of 2020/07/20 on top of 2020/07/23

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: Of course... I tried explaining how to deal with the label caption. In order to start the adding process you need to clear the label caption before the iteration. I will edit my question and show you how to proceed...  Did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub.

```
Sub MultiLineLabel()
 Dim DateChosen As Date
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim myCaption
 
 DateChosen = "2020/07/20"
        For i = 10 To 5000
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = DateChosen Then
                myCaption = myCaption & Range("F" & i) & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next i
        
    EventLabel.Caption = myCaption
End Sub
```